# ng2-carouselamos: previous & next buttons not working in IE 11 browser

Tags: javascript, angular5

I am using [ng2-carouselamos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-carouselamos) in my application (I am using Angular-5). It is working perfect in Chrome & Firefox. But in IE 11, next & previous button click events are not working (throwing console error).

Please suggest some solution.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

in src/polyfills.ts, search for the following comment and uncomment the following lines...

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: These lines are already uncommented in polyfills.ts. This solution doesn't help.